# How to fix "execution of 'Constant' statements is denied" error?

Tags: python, constants, web.py

I'm following the tutorial in web.py documentation for templates

```
    import web
    render = web.template.render('templates')
    print (render.hello('world'))
```

However when running the python file results in an error :"execution of 'Constant' statements is denied". Google searching doesn't turn up any answers,I need some help please. Thank You

Comment: It's not a python error, it's a security violation from web.py. Something in your template is trying to execute python code which is being denied by web.py --- what's your "hello" template look like?

Comment: @pbuck 
My hello template is a hello.html file with only these few lines of code inside

`$def with (name)
Hello $name!`

Comment: For some reason it works fine on my linux machine, this error only occurs on my windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web.py disallows some types of python legal statements to be executed within the template. I don't know why it's disallowing your particular statement, but there's a way to allow templates to do more:

web/template.py contains a list `ALLOWED_AST_NODES` which are constructs (used by the abstract syntax tree parser) which are permitted in within templates. You can change that.

In your code, add once:

```
from web.template import ALLOWED_AST_NODES
ALLOWED_AST_NODES.append('Constant')
```

Now, this shouldn't be necessary, so I suspect there's something else going on in your code.... mix of versions, perhaps? I believe 'Constant' is a node in python3 AST, but not in python2?

This is a useful technique to add dictionary comprehension `.append('DictComp')` to the template allowed ast nodes as it already permits list comprehension.